# How to optimize for performance when querying millions of rows in real-time analytics?

Tags: postgresql, performance, database-design, timescaledb, time-series-database

Suppose I have a simple table called `events` like this:

| timestamp | event_id | action_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apr 5 01:05:00 | foo | 10 |
| apr 5 01:04:15 | bar | 20 |
| apr 5 01:06:10 | baz | 200 |
| apr 5 01:04:30 | baz | 5 |
| apr 5 01:03:00 | baz | 1 |
| apr 5 01:03:02 | foo | 3 |
| apr 5 01:03:02 | bar | 100 |
| apr 5 01:01:00 | bar | 34 |

Given this table, for any given interval, such as `last minute`, `last hour`, `last 10 hours` and so on, I'd like to extract the following data:

| event_id | total_action_count |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 500 |
| bar | 499 |
| baz | 300 |

---

Simple enough, right?

```
SELECT event_id,
       SUM(event_count) as total_action_count
FROM events
GROUP BY event_id
ORDER BY total_action_count DESC
```

However, I'm finding that this doesn't scale, at least not well enough for querying it every second, for multiple intervals, when dealing with millions of rows per day, and tens of thousands of unique `event_id`.

With a setup pretty similar to this one, using timescaledb with Postgres, a query on 2.5m events and 30k unique `event_id` over a 24 hour period is taking anywhere from 2 to 5 seconds. Considering I want to run this query every second or so for 10 different intervals, this approach simply doesn't work.

From my perspective, my bottleneck is the fact that I can't get around having to read every single row to SUM `action_count` per `event_id`. In this example I could in theory have one row for each `action_count` instead, but for my real use case I can't because `action_count` can be a number anywhere from 1 to 10 billion.

So, my question is, **is there any way I could model this in such a way that I can run these queries *much* faster**?

Keep in mind, it's no use for me to keep track of events on a hourly/daily timeframe, since I'm always querying on last N minutes/hours instead of hour N or day N.
With timescaledb I could bucket my data into minute/hour intervals, but since I have tens of thousands of unique `event_id` I end up running into the same bottleneck of having to read and sum millions of rows at a time.

Another caveat is that rows are usually, but not always, coming in the correct order. So I may insert and event for April 5 followed by an event for March 30 and then April 5 again.

I can think of a few solutions, but they all seem extremely contrived and error prone. I could also use a memory database, but it seems to me that there's got to be a better solution to all of this, right?

So, I'm asking you, how would you approach this?

Comment: I would prepare the results of the query when registering the events.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille That was my first instinct, ad that would be fine if I needed data for a fixed interval like "day N" or "hour N", but since I need "last N hours" or "last N minutes" that doesn't really work, right? I can group events into buckets, like "minute apr-5-05:05" and hour "april-5-05", which timescaledb can do for me, but I still end up with too much data to run fast queries. It might very well be that there's no way around this though, I'm just hoping there's a magical pattern out there that I'm overlooking.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille it's also possible I didn't fully understand your suggestion as I'm not familiar with the PREPARE statement. If you could give me a pseudo-example of what you mean or point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I think I'd have a table for each used interval, containing only the most recent data, deleting what's too old before each query.  An index on the timestamp would allow to find those quite fast.  I'm not familiar with the prepare statement either.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I see what you mean. While that works, I end up back with the same problem given a long enough interval. My current performance for 5 minutes or 1 hour is fine, but from 12 hours on things get tricky. I'm looking into continuous aggregates on timescaledb now, which could accomplish something similar to what you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: "..since I need "last N hours" or "last N minutes" that doesn't really work, right?.." No. If you have stored running total for each `event_id` then you can calculate the sum of `action_count` for arbitrary interval as a difference of two `running_total`s at its boundaries.

Comment: "Another caveat is that rows are usually, but not always, coming in the correct order. So I may insert and event for April 5 followed by an event for March 30 and then April 5 again."  Is there time period after which you can be confident no more stragglers will be showing up?

Comment: It is really hard to believe you will be looking at 24 hours worth of data, yet need a brand new answer every second.  What the heck will you be doing with these answers?  But for each second, you only really need to look at the previous answer, plus the data added for the past second, and that which expired in the past second.

Comment: @jjanes As for your first comment, yet, I'd say after 5-10 minutes it's safe to assume there won't be any stragglers.
Regarding your second comment, it may sound unusual but that's correct, I need a new answer every second for 24 hour data. Picture something like real time Google Analytics, where I want to see 24h pageviews per page in realtime. The data itself is simple, just a count, but I do need an accurate answer.
I agree with you though, if I run the query 10 times within 30 seconds only 1% of all data actually changed, I'm just having a hard time dealing with that efficiently.

Comment: @Kondybas You're right about that. That's actually why I chose timescaledb. It works well for historical data, but for the example I gave, this method doesn't seem to be very effective because I have too many unique event_ids. Case in point, using timescaledb I can group all my data into hourly buckets, but I still need [unique event ids * 24] rows. Using some mock data, with this method I can go from 2.5m rows I have to read to 1.8m rows. It helps, but it's not really the solution I'm looking for. Keep in mind, I do need data for each and every unique event_id, therein lies the problem.

Comment: Can you share more details about the table structure? Did you enable compression? Have you added any segment by event_id?

I think this is a perfect case for the continuous aggregates.

Comment: @jonatasdp No compression, not sure what you mean by segment. I thought continuous aggregates would be perfect here as well, but I can't accurately get last N hours from continuous aggregates. For instance, I can get 1pm, 2pm and partial 3pm, but I can't get 1:30pm to 3:30pm. I could with smaller buckets, but I end up needing 1 minute buckets to fit my desired intervals and then I'm back at square one having to loop millions of rows. My current solution is to just throw more CPU at it, it seems there's no magical solution here, unfortunately :/

Comment: Give a try on enabling compression. When you compress the data, it also allows you to segment your data by some specific column. So, it fits quite well on `event_id` if it will be repeated as an identifier of something. https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/compression/about-compression/#procedure-enabling-compression